# Multiple Logistic Regression in Python

Tags: python, regression

I have a data set as such:

```
0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,5
1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,3
1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1
0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,4
```

I'm looking for a way to run logistic regression in python which uses several discrete values (0 or 1) to predict a numerical value (between 1-5). This seems useful but it assumes the predictor variable is also discrete: http://www.mblondel.org/tlml/logreg.py.html#

Any suggestions?

Comment: LR usually assumes the predicted value is discrete or the probability of a discrete outcome. Maybe you want something like [ordinal LR](http://www.stat.ubc.ca/~rollin/teach/643w04/lec/node62.html)?

Comment: Any suggestions if the predicted value is discrete? I could use both with my data.

Comment: It's for Cross Validated, not for StackOverFlow

Answer (score 0):

If getting the job done in R (through one of rpy2, pyRserve, or pyper) is an option, you could this to get the job done. If questions about the statistical method to use, this "cross-validated" is a better place to ask.